# Fresh forms builder for oracle forms6i

Tags: oracle, forms

can you recommend me a froms builder for oracle forms6i? on our work we use forms6i, but it is outdated long ago, its not comfort to use. But in our work we use 6i, cause all projects buided on it.
Can i use some other soft to buid 6i valid forms?

Comment: If you want to upgrade Forms, Oracle has almost 20 years of upgrades available. I don't understand why you would want to update the Forms builder but not the core product. http://www.vesterli.com/2008/01/31/oracle-forms-6i-officially-unsupported-tomorrow/

Comment: Couse all product that now running use forms 6i. our high managers dont want to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Forms is a proprietary Oracle format and Forms Builder is the only supported tool for working with it.

Obviously it is a fairly old tool but what exact problems make it uncomfortable to use? Have you explored the C API and JDAPI libraries for programmatic manipulation in C and Java?

Comment: uncomfort as tool, not intuitive. we have planty good oracle developer tools, but no forms. we use only 6i forms for desktop apps

Comment: Intuition is in the eye of the beholder. I haven't used Forms in fifteen years but I could probably knock up an application in no time